# Equivalent code in jQuery when integrating another library

Tags: jquery, ajax, mootools

I am using [MooTools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools) 1.11 and [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) 1.2. The Ajax function is not working properly for the following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    confirm("Hello");
    function confirm(message){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            ....
        });
     }
});
```

What modification should I do to execute the Ajax function correctly?

Comment: An aside: jQuery 1.3.1 has been released, and has some great new features and performance boosts in it: you should think about upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`confirm`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php) is a built-in function (a reserved name)... try using a different name for it.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe (it's untested) you can use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery.noConflict(true)) {
```

And still use `$` inside.